# Enabling Lightning

Tags: lightning

When the Lightning is enabled in an org will it break anything that is not supported in Lightning UI while a user uses Classic UI?
The thing is that some of the users need to stay in Classic UI and some will move to Lightning UI.
My question is - won't switching Lightning on in org disable forecasting (for example) or Opportunity Split? Won't it break installed packages?

EDIT 1

I'm aware of Lightning limitations. I'm interested in not breaking functionality in Classic UI while Lightning is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

On the installed packages point, Salesforce has a "Lightning Ready" banner on the AppExchange that is added to packages that have been tested to ensure that:

> 100% of your End-User Use Cases must work as expected in Lightning
>   Experience. It is not necessary to re-style your app or use Lightning
>   Components.

But this typically requires some work to achieve and so a new version of the managed package which in turn means you may need to upgrade installed packages to get the "Lightning Ready" versions.

Comment: Yes, but will 'not Lightning Ready' package work in Classic UI?

Comment: @Chiz I misunderstood your question - yes if a Classic app is made Lightning Ready it will still work in the Classic UI i.e. it should work in both.

Comment: Yes, but if app is NOT 'Lightning Ready', will it still work in Classic UI while org is switched to Lightning?

Comment: @Chiz I have several orgs with Lightning Experience enabled and have not seen any Classic code fail - the Classic environment just gets an extra switch in its UI. So my answer is "yes". Adding/changing profiles does require planning though.